# Proof a quantified predicate logic statement

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers

I am having trouble really understanding how to prove this

$$(S(y) \to T(y)) \land S(x) \to (∃x)T(x).$$

My solution so far is:

1. $S(y) \to T(y)$ ---   Hypothesis
2. $S(x)$ ---    Hypothesis
3. $T(y)$ --- Modus Ponens of 1 and 2
4. $(∃x)T(x)$ --- Existential Generalization of 3

It seems incorrect to me due to the usage of x and y.  Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that there is a "missing" quantifier in front of $(S(y) \to T(y))$...

You cannot prove the formula :

> $(S(y) \to T(y)) ∧ S(x) \to (∃x)T(x)$

because it is **not** *valid*.

Consider as *domain* of the interpretation the set $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers and interpret the two predicates $S(x), T(x)$ as : $(x=0)$ and $(x < o)$ respectively.

With this interpretation the above formula "means" :

> $((y=0) \to (y < 0)) ∧ (x=0) \to (∃x)(x < 0)$.

Consider now a *variavle assignment* $s$ such that $s(x)=0$ and $s(y)=1$; then :

> $(((y=0) \to (y < 0)) ∧ (x=0) \to (∃x)(x < 0))[s]$

is *false*, because : $((1=0) \to (1 < 0))$ is *true* and also : $(0=0)$ is *true*, while : $\exists x(x < 0)$ is clearly *false* in $\mathbb N$.

Thus :

> > $\mathbb N \nvDash (((y=0) \to (y < 0)) ∧ (x=0) \to (∃x)(x < 0))[s]$

and thus, having found an interpretation and a variable assignment such that the formula is not *satisfied*, we have to conclude that the formula is not *valid* and thus, by *soundness*, is not provable.

---

*Note*

If we "restore" the formula with an universal quantifier :

$\forall y(S(y) \to T(y)) ∧ S(x) \to (∃x)T(x)$

then your "proof startegy" will work :

1) $\forall y(S(y) \to T(y))$ --- hypothesis

2) $S(x)$ --- hypothesis

3) $S(x) \to T(x)$ --- from 1) by [Universal Instantiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation)

4) $T(x)$ --- Modus Ponens from 2) and 3)

> 5) $(∃x)T(x)$ --- from 4) by [Existential Generalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_generalization)